# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toast

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en kotlin, intento hacer un debug pero me aparece lo siguiente y no me deja usarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo del LoginActivity.kt

la linea 18 es setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mAuth: FirebaseAuth by lazy { FirebaseAuth.getInstance() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        buttonLogIn_LoginAc.setOnClickListener {
            val email = editTextEmail_LoginAc.text.toString()
            val password = editTextPassword_LoginAc.text.toString()
            if (isValidEmailAndPassword(email, password)){
                logInByEmail(email, password)
            }
        }

        textViewForgotPassword_LoginAc.setOnClickListener {
            goToActivity<ForgotPasswordActivity>()
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
        }

        buttonCreateAccount_LoginAc.setOnClickListener {
            goToActivity<SignUpActivity>()
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
        }
    }

    private fun logInByEmail(email: String, password: String){
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this) {task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                toast("User is now logg in")
            }else {

                toast("an unexpected error occurred, please try again.")
            }
        }
    }
    private fun isValidEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String): Boolean{
        return !email.isNullOrEmpty() && !password.isNullOrEmpty()
    }}
```

este el gradle app

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el gradle proyect 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es curioso porque cuando ejecuto el app en el activity de loginActivity no me muestra los Toast a comparación de los otros activities que si los muestran.

posdata: YA intente rebuild proyect, clean proyect , invalidate Cache and Restart y nada...

por la atención que le presten a mi pequeño error (si es que es un error) estaré altamente agradecido-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es un error reportado:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117685087

pero en realidad estas usando método agregado en la API 28:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

puedes cambiar a :

```
minSdkVersion 28
```

otra solución es agregar en tu archivo `app/build.gradle` :

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "26.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me funciono ya, muchas gracias amigo...

Comment: Excelente, saludos @DcTerrance